# Can I run virtualized 64-bit Operating Systems if my CPU doesn't support VT-X?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vmware-workstation, vt-x

I have installed VMWare 10.0 workstation on my Compaq CQ60-615DX laptop. The Operating System is Windows 7 Home Premium.

When I tried to run Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit in a virtual machine in VMWare I get an error saying:

> This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems.
>   However, 64-bit operation is not possible.
>
> This host does not support Intel VT-x.
>
> For more detailed information, see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.

So I googled and found that I have to [enable Intel VT-x](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8978). But I found out that my processor [doesn't support](http://ark.intel.com/products/41498/Intel-Celeron-Processor-900-1M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) `Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x)`.

So am I doomed and can I never run any virtual OS on my laptop? Or can I run 32-bit OSes?

Comment: Indeed.  What you want is not possible with the hardware you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only run 32-bit OSes without having Intel VT-x enabled when using VMWare. You can try the Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit version.